# Links and assets in grails contains no prefix, grails.app.context not working

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, virtualhost

I'm trying to deploy a Grails 2.5.3 application on a Tomcat 7 server, running behind Apache (apache running on http://valkyrien.imada.sdu.dk:80). Tomcat is running on port `8080` and Apache virtualhost is setup like this:

```
ProxyPass /gcp http://127.0.0.1:8080/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /gcp http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

The war is deployed as `ROOT.war` to Tomcat's `/webapps/` directory.
The index page of my grails application is shown, but the links on the page along with the asset links are wrong. None of them are prefixed with `/gcp/`.

Example: The javascript asset for jQuery at the html file is:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-8c9c0e26152ea554b3ed6c4390439134.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Which will try to access the js file at `<APACHE-URL>/assets/jquery-8c9c0e26152ea554b3ed6c4390439134.js` even though the file is in fact available at `<APACHE-URL>/gcp/assets/jquery-8c9c0e26152ea554b3ed6c4390439134.js`. The same apply to any link to controllers and actions.

Adding any combination of the following to `Config.groovy` or application.properties does not change anything (as suggested by answers on StackOverflow):

```
grails.serverURL="http://valkyrien.imada.sdu.dk/gcp"
grails.app.context = "/gcp"
```

It seems like Grails ignores the serverURL properties. Any suggestions toward why this is not working?
Running without Apache is not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy your app not as `ROOT.war` but as `gcp.war` and updated properties

...or better use [mod_jk](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html) for apache.

Comment: Deploying as `gcp.war` results in a blank (white) page when accessing `/gcp`. This is with and without the mentioned configurations of `Config.groovy` and `application.properties`.

Comment: But the assets is available at:
`<APACHE-URL>/gcp/gcp/assets/bootstrap-c39cd1b8a453e91be3e945bc64eb26a9.css` etc.
And accessing [/gcp/gcp/](http://valkyrien.imada.sdu.dk/gcp/gcp/) results in a 404 response with "/index.gsp" not found.

Comment: Did you updated also `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` to new path? If yes - show it.

Comment: Update it? I'm not sure what you mean. They are already pointing to the /gcp "subdirectory".

Comment: I just realized what you meant. Tomcat is now running the app at localhost:8080/gcp, so Apache should also proxy the /gcp request to this location. Unfortunately I don't have access to the VirtualHost config at the moment. Will test later. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. But instead of playing with sophisticated rules check mod_jk for apache. We use it on production.